# MySQL: How to display only the minimum count without the use of limit?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, output, min

The logical error here is that the output displays like this:

```
+-----------------+-------+----------+-------+
| registration_no | color | producer | count |
+-----------------+-------+----------+-------+
| X23-234         | green | VW       |     2 |
| BC-343          | red   | BMW      |     2 |
| TW-435          | blue  | Ford     |     1 |
| 232-444         | pink  | Army     |     2 |
+-----------------+-------+----------+-------+
```

As you can see the minimum count is the color blue and I want it to display only this:

```
| TW-435          | blue  | Ford     |
```

The derired query should not limit keyword only nested query.
Here is my sql query:

```
mysql> SELECT registration_no, color, producer, COUNT(*) as count 
       FROM car, car_type, booking 
       WHERE car.car_type_id = car_type.car_type_id and booking.car_id = car.car_id 
       GROUP BY car.car_id;
```

I just can't figure out the solution.

Comment: have you tried `min` aggregate function ?

Comment: You can use 'Order By Count asc' And 'LIMIT 1' (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: yes I tried the min(count) but it displays an error "Invalid use of group function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order by count(*) and then limit at the first row

```
SELECT registration_no, color, producer, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM car, car_type, booking 
WHERE car.car_type_id = car_type.car_type_id and booking.car_id =car.car_id 
GROUP BY car.car_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

this works if you only want just one row. In case you have more rows with `count(*) = 1` then you should use another method

if you want to show the highest count just sort descending

```
....
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

but in this case you'll get one of the 3 rows having `count = 2` and not all the three rows

Comment: How about if i decided to display the highest count what would be the query?

Answer (score 0):

Order by the count and take only the first element with `limit`

```
SELECT registration_no, color, producer, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM car
join car_type on car.car_type_id = car_type.car_type_id
JOIN booking on booking.car_id = car.car_id 
GROUP BY car.car_id
order by count asc
limit 1
```

And BTW use the explicit join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT registration_no, color, producer
FROM (
    SELECT registration_no, color, producer, COUNT(*) as count 
    FROM car, car_type, booking 
    WHERE car.car_type_id = car_type.car_type_id and booking.car_id = car.car_id 
    GROUP BY car.car_id) DT
ORDER BY count
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: How to remove the count display? I want only the other display except the count.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query in order to select the min count:

```
select min(count) from (select COUNT(*) as count 
   FROM car, car_type, booking 
   WHERE car.car_type_id = car_type.car_type_id and booking.car_id = car.car_id 
   GROUP BY car.car_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT registration_no, color, producer 
FROM car, car_type, booking 
WHERE car.car_type_id = car_type.car_type_id and booking.car_id =car.car_id 
GROUP BY car.car_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
LIMIT 1;
+-----------------+-------+----------+
| registration_no | color | producer |
+-----------------+-------+----------+
| TW-435          | blue  | Ford     |
+-----------------+-------+----------+
1 row in set
```